# "Spontaneous", "voluntary" and "involuntary"

Tags: meaning, synonyms, antonyms

I was looking for a synonym of *spontaneous*, and *voluntary* naturally came to my mind. In an attempt to understand the difference between them, I tried to google *spontaneous vs voluntary*. To my surprise, nothing really interesting popped up from search results.

Then I decided to look them up respectively. As expected, *voluntary* is listed as a synonym of *spontaneous* according to many online resources, and vice versa. However, to my great shock, *involuntary* is also listed as a synonym of *spontaneous* by major online dictionaries.

Although the fact does not necessarily imply *voluntary* and *involuntary* are synonyms, I continued to look further into *voluntary vs involuntary* due to confusion.

I found that a *voluntary* action is something that is done voluntarily or with meaning to do so, while an *involuntary* action on the other hand is done
*automatically*.

Now I'm even more confused. The word *automatically* just reminds me of *spontaneously*, convincing me to believe *involuntary* is indeed a synonym of *spontaneous* while *voluntary* seems less so.

Could someone please justify or explain the contradictions mentioned above? I'm totally lost.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A *voluntary* action is one that the actor, employing free will, chooses to take.

An *involuntary* action is one that takes place out of the control of the actor, or against the actor's will.

*Spontaneous* has several related definitions. A spontaneous action can be one that the actor takes without a significant amount of forethought ("a spontaneous purchase"). In that case, the spontaneous action is voluntary.

On the other hand, *spontaneous* can also refer to something that occurs with no apparent cause ("spontaneous combustion"). By its nature, this activity rarely involves an overt "actor" per se. When it involves a living organism ("spontaneous growth", "spontaneous motion", etc.), the action is probably involuntary.

*Spontaneous* has a few other definitions as well. Generally, you'll have to discern the difference from context. When you see the word "spontaneous" used to describe an action taken by a clearly definable actor, though, the action is probably voluntary (although it might not be).

Comment: I think spontaneous combustion is a good example of spontaneously/involuntary :)

Answer (score 3):

Even though voluntary is the opposite of involuntary, they do have something in common.
Consider the following meanings:

- Voluntary describes an action taken by an actor without being compelled to do so by someone else.
- Involuntary describes an action performed without the actor's will.
- Spontaneous is something that happens without intervention of something else.

All three cases involve something which does not interfere with the action.

- voluntary: EXTERNAL ENTITY **does not interfere with** ACTOR performing ACTION.
- involuntary: ACTOR **does not interfere with** ACTION

So both are spontaneous, but with a different *non-interfering* part.

Comment: -1. This is not a good answer. Your definition of spontaneous is a secondary definition of the word that only applies to natural phenomena, and is inapplicable to voluntary or involuntary actions.